# Encrypted cookies in Chrome

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, cookies

I am currently working on a C# forms application that needs to access a specific cookie on my computer, which I can do perfectly fine. Here's the issue:

Google stores cookies in SQLite, and I've downloaded Sqlite database browser to help me look at these values. What surprises me is that about half of the cookie values shows as empty (including the one I need), even though they are obviously not.

The db file is located at:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies
```

On Chrome I have an addon called "Edit This Cookie" which allows me to directly modify cookies on the website I'm on. This addon can read these cookies, and the web browser can parse values through HTTP when needed for different requests, so they are definitely there - still, the SQLite browser, and my custom code both come to the conclusion that the particular value field is empty.

Why is that?
What is it that somehow prevents the field from being read by certain applications?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Alright, so in case anyone is interested, I found a solution to this problem after alot of trial, error and googling.

Google Chrome cookies DB has 2 columns for storing values: "value" and "encrypted_value", the latter being used when the cookie stored was requested to be encrypted - often the case with certain confidential information and long-time session keys.

After figuring this out, I then needed to find a way to access this key, stored as a Blob value. I found several guides on how to do this, but the one that ended up paying off was: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/56109/Reading-BLOB-in-Sqlite-using-C-NET-CF-PPC

Simply reading the value is not enough, as it is encrypted. - Google Chrome uses triple DES encryption with the current users password as seed on windows machines. In order to decrypt this in C#, one should use Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI), there are a few guides out there on how to make use of it.

Answer (score 31):

I've run into this same problem, and the code below provides a working example for anyone who is interested. All credit to Scherling, as the DPAPI was spot on.

```
public class ChromeCookieReader
{
    public IEnumerable<Tuple<string,string>> ReadCookies(string hostName)
    {
        if (hostName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("hostName");

        var dbPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies";
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(dbPath)) throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("Cant find cookie store",dbPath); // race condition, but i'll risk it

        var connectionString = "Data Source=" + dbPath + ";pooling=false";

        using (var conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            var prm = cmd.CreateParameter();
            prm.ParameterName = "hostName";
            prm.Value = hostName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name,encrypted_value FROM cookies WHERE host_key = @hostName";

            conn.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var encryptedData = (byte[]) reader[1];
                    var decodedData = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedData, null, System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
                    var plainText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decodedData); // Looks like ASCII

                    yield return Tuple.Create(reader.GetString(0), plainText);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your variable 'hostName' contain?

Comment: An example would be stackoverflow.com, which would resolve the cookes for this site.

Comment: is there any function that can work on MAC for "System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect"?

Comment: Don't you need a key to decrypt the value?

Comment: Hi Jasper, would you consider updating your answer to include the information listed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60611673/6481581 as Google Chrome version 80 and up use a different technique to decrypt the cookie.

Answer (score 9):

Like Jasper's answer, in a PowerShell script (of course, customize the SQL query to your needs, and the path to your cookies location):

```
$cookieLocation = 'C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\cookies'
$tempFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

"select writefile('$tempFileName', encrypted_value) from cookies where host_key = 'localhost' and path = '/api' and name = 'sessionId';" | sqlite3.exe "$cookieLocation"
$cookieAsEncryptedBytes = Get-Content -Encoding Byte "$tempFileName"
Remove-Item "$tempFileName"

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
$cookieAsBytes = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect($cookieAsEncryptedBytes, $null, [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser)
$cookie = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($cookieAsBytes)
$cookie
```

Comment: **SHORT VERSION:** `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security;` `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect($(Get-Content -Encoding Byte "YOUR_FILENAME.BIN"), $null, [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser))`

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that Google Chrome encrypts the data you need to read, so you have to decrypt it.
First, get a copy of the cookies file. Then read it using SQLite3. After that, get the encrypted bytes. And last, use the code below to decrypt it.
You'll need these Nugets:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

The code so far:

```
        File.Copy(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA") + @"/../Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Cookies", @"./Cookies",true);
        SQLiteConnection Cnn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + @"./Cookies" + ";pooling=false");
        Cnn.Open();

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT host_key, name, value, encrypted_value FROM cookies WHERE name='mvrusername' OR name='mvrcookie' OR name='mikuki4'", Cnn);
        SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            byte[] encryptedData = (byte[])rdr["encrypted_value"];
            string encKey = File.ReadAllText(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA") + @"/../Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Local State");
            encKey = JObject.Parse(encKey)["os_crypt"]["encrypted_key"].ToString();
            var decodedKey = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(encKey).Skip(5).ToArray(), null, System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);

            const int MAC_BIT_SIZE = 128;
            const int NONCE_BIT_SIZE = 96;

            using (var cipherStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedData))
            using (var cipherReader = new BinaryReader(cipherStream))
            {
                var nonSecretPayload = cipherReader.ReadBytes(3);
                var nonce = cipherReader.ReadBytes(NONCE_BIT_SIZE / 8);
                var cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesEngine());
                var parameters = new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(decodedKey), MAC_BIT_SIZE, nonce);
                cipher.Init(false, parameters);
                var cipherText = cipherReader.ReadBytes(encryptedData.Length);
                var plainText = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(cipherText.Length)];
                try
                {
                    var len = cipher.ProcessBytes(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length, plainText, 0);
                    cipher.DoFinal(plainText, len);
                }
                catch (InvalidCipherTextException)
                {
                }
                string _cookie= Encoding.Default.GetString(plainText);

            }
        }
```

// Big thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60611673/6481581 for answering how Chrome 80 and up changed the way cookies are encrypted.

Comment: Does your solution work for Chrome 80+?

Answer (score 1):

So I wanted to do this without writing to a tempfile every time but also without implementing a separate class as per jasper's solution.  Like [jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472232/jasper), I found it easier and quicker to access the System.Data.SQLite.dll available [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).  It's not as elegant as a separate class, but it's what worked best for me:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\System.Data.SQLite\2015\bin\x64\System.Data.SQLite.dll'

Function Get-Last-Cookie {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] $valueName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] $hostKey,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] $dbDataSource
    )

    $conn = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$dbDataSource"
    $conn.Open()

    $command = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $query = "SELECT encrypted_value FROM cookies WHERE name='$valueName' `
              AND host_key='$hostKey' ORDER BY creation_utc DESC LIMIT 1"
    $command.CommandText = $query
    $adapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter $command
    $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    [void]$adapter.Fill($dataset)
    $command.Dispose();
    $conn.Close();
    $cookieAsEncryptedBytes = $dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0]
    $cookieAsBytes = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect($cookieAsEncryptedBytes, $null, [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser)
    return [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($cookieAsBytes)
}

$localAppDataPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::LocalApplicationData)
$cookieDbPath = 'Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies'
$dbDataSource = Join-Path -Path $localAppDataPath -ChildPath $cookieDbPath

$plainCookie = Get-Last-Cookie 'acct' '.stackoverflow.com' $dbDataSource
Write-Host $plainCookie
```

I also found the [Add-SqliteAssembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552588/using-sqlite-from-powershell-on-windows-7x64) function by [halr9000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6637/halr9000) to be very helpful when it came time to schedule my script in the windows task scheduler and realized that the task scheduler runs the x86 version of PowerShell and thus SQLite rather than the x64 I was using in the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # this powershell scripts exports your cookies to a format curl and wget understand
    # Obs ! Each profile has its own cookes file , replace me (ysg ;o) with your win usr name
    # aka wget -x --load-cookies cookies.txt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532870/encrypted-cookies-in-chrome

    $cookieLocation = 'C:\Users\ysg\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Cookies'
    $curl_cookies_file="C:\var\ygeo.reports.app.futurice.com.cookies.doc-pub-host.txt"
    $tempFileName1 = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    $tempFileName2 = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

    # adjust your filter in the where clause ...
    "select writefile('$tempFileName1', encrypted_value) from cookies where host_key = '.futurice.com' ;" | sqlite3.exe "$cookieLocation"
    $cookieAsEncryptedBytes = Get-Content -Encoding Byte "$tempFileName1"
    Remove-Item "$tempFileName1"


    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
    $cookieAsBytes = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect($cookieAsEncryptedBytes, $null, [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser)
    $cookie = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($cookieAsBytes)
    $unquoted_cookie=$cookie -replace '"', ""

    # adjust your filter in the where clause ...
    "
    select  
        host_key
     , CASE WHEN httponly=0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END
     , path
     , CASE WHEN secure=0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END
     , expires_utc
     , name 
     , '$unquoted_cookie'
    from cookies where host_key = '.futurice.com' ;" | sqlite3.exe -separator " " "$cookieLocation" > $curl_cookies_file

    Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_) | Out-File -Encoding ASCII $_ }

    # check the meta data table
    #"PRAGMA table_info([cookies]);" | sqlite3.exe "$cookieLocation"

    # src: https://github.com/daftano/cookies.txt/blob/master/src/popup.js
    #content += escapeForPre(cookie.domain);
    #content += "\t";
    #content += escapeForPre((!cookie.hostOnly).toString().toUpperCase());
    #content += "\t";     
    #content += escapeForPre(cookie.path); 
    #content += "\t";     
    #content += escapeForPre(cookie.secure.toString().toUpperCase());
    #content += "\t";     
    #content += escapeForPre(cookie.expirationDate ? Math.round(cookie.expirationDate) : "0");
    #content += "\t";     
    #content += escapeForPre(cookie.name);
    #content += "\t";     
    #content += escapeForPre(cookie.value);
    #content += "\n";
    #
    #0|creation_utc|INTEGER|1||1
    #1|host_key|TEXT|1||0
    #2|name|TEXT|1||0
    #3|value|TEXT|1||0
    #4|path|TEXT|1||0
    #5|expires_utc|INTEGER|1||0
    #6|secure|INTEGER|1||0
    #7|httponly|INTEGER|1||0
    #8|last_access_utc|INTEGER|1||0
    #9|has_expires|INTEGER|1|1|0
    #10|persistent|INTEGER|1|1|0
    #11|priority|INTEGER|1|1|0
    #12|encrypted_value|BLOB|0|''|0
    #13|firstpartyonly|INTEGER|1|0|0
```

Answer (score -8):

Just set "value" to the cookie you want, "encrypted_value" to NULL and "priority" to 0

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense at all. What you want to do is decrypt the encrypted value. Setting it to NULL will cause you to lose the value.