# Why doesn't SqliteConnection open the connection?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I tried to create a saved password reader in Chrome but when I open the connection in Sqllite it fails p.s. var conn is not null. The only error I can notice is in ServerVersion = <'conn.ServerVversion' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'>

```cs
public IEnumerable<CredentialModel> ReadPasswords()
{
    var result = new List<CredentialModel>();

    var appdata = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    var p = Path.GetFullPath(appdata + LOGIN_DATA_PATH);

    if (File.Exists(p))
    {
        using (var conn = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={p};"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins";
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            var pass = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ProtectedData.Unprotect(GetBytes(reader, 2), null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser));

                            result.Add(new CredentialModel()
                            {
                                Url = reader.GetString(0),
                                Username = reader.GetString(1),
                                Password = pass
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Canno find chrome logins file");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is `conn.ServerVversion` in the error message a typo, or is that the actual message? If it's not a typo, there's an extra `v`. I don't see that code in what you posted though.

Comment: Are you using latest SQL Driver?  The Net driver is probably different from the chrome driver.  You may have an old SQLLite driver.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/

Comment: @Diado if I check conn in ServerVersion it says ServerVersion 'conn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' string {System.NullReferenceException}

Comment: The extra `v` is presumably a typo then. At what stage in the code are you checking `conn.ServerVersion`?

Comment: @FrancescoBuscicchio that doesn't mean anything. Just because a property can't be read in the Watch Window doesn't mean the class is broken.  Do you get an exception in the code? What is the *exact* text returned by `Exception.ToString()`? Do you get an exception because the connection string is invalid perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos {"Reference to an object not set to an object instance."}

Comment: @FrancescoBuscicchio that's not the exception's text, that's a JSON string generated by just the `Message` part. Post the **full** exception text. That includes the exact line where the error occurred and the chain of calls that led to it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ex.Source = 'SQLitePCLRaw.core'
ex.StackTrace = '   at SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_open_v2(String filename, sqlite3& db, Int32 flags, String vfs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()
   at Password_Tracker.ChromePassReader.ReadPasswords() in C:\Users\francesco.buscicchio\source\repos\Password Tracker\ChromePassReader.cs:line 31'

Comment: Please post the *full exception text in the query itself*, not just parts of it. Are you *sure* the path is correct? Have you checked the value of `p`? `Environment.GetFolderPath` doesn't return a trailing `\\`. Use `Path.Combine` to create paths

Answer (score 2):

Your project is referencing `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core`, which also requires work to setup [which native SQLite library to use](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw).
It seems that the native SQLite driver is not setup correctly in your case.

For an easier experience, reference `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` which pre-configures the SQLite to use.

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18827#issuecomment-552659874)

Comment: If I add Version = 3 it goes into exception (Keyword not supported: 'version'.)

Comment: I 've checked some other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047326/null-values-when-reading-from-chrome-sqlite-cookie-database) and it seems that Version=3 is a valid keyword. Which sqlite driver/version are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core.3.1.7

Comment: @FrancescoBuscicchio see my updated answer. Basically you should use `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.3.1.7` instead of `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core.3.1.7`

Comment: @FrancescoBuscicchio please mark it as the answer if it helped you.