# How to read an encrypted Chrome cookie from local file

Tags: python, google-chrome, cookies, tripledes

I'm trying to read the local cookies file for Google Chrome, which is located at `C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies` and can be read using sqlite3 in Python. I can then get the encrypted value in Python using `sqlite3` by doing the following:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT encrypted_value FROM 'cookies' WHERE name = <some name>")
val = c.fetchall()
```

The normal value for this cookie is a blank `TEXT`, and the `encrypted_value` is a `BLOB` data type. I was looking for what `BLOB` is and it looks like it's just a big binary piece of data that is encrypted. Looking more into this, I think I found that Chrome uses triple DES encryption. Is there any way I can decrypt this from my computer using Python?

Comment: On Windows Chrome uses the DPAPI, See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532870/encrypted-cookies-in-chrome?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa for details.

Comment: https://geekswipe.net/technology/computing/swoop-chrome-passwords-decrypt-with-python/