# Chrome cookie not up-to-date

Tags: c#, google-chrome, cookies

In my Winforms project, I can get a cookie of a site opened in IE by the following method :

```
InternetGetCookie("mysite.com", "mycookie", "something" , "something" )
```

As a new requirement coming, the site must be opened in Chrome. That means the method above doesn't work anymore.

After some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532870/encrypted-cookies-in-chrome), I found out a solution to use `Sqlite` to read the `cookies` file stored in `"Users\xx\AppData\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\cookies"`, it works as expected. I can fetch the cookie by giving the name and URL.

BUT PROBLEM: The cookies file is not up-to-date and is updated 1-2 minutes laters. That means the cookies of the request shown in Chrome DevTool is not the same as in the `cookies` file.

Is there any way to fetch the cookie in Chrome from C# Winforms project similar to `InternetGetCookie`?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, there doesn't seem to be a chrome flag to flush this quicker so probably not going to be an easy option... You could maybe:

Grab it from memory (may be possible if you can search for the value somehow)

Write a Chrome extension which dumps it immediately

Use a headless browser instance to visit the site and send the cookie back instead