# python selenium chrome cookie database is empty

Tags: python, google-chrome, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make a cookie scanner that gets all cookies from a website.
My approach was to open a website with Selenium ChromeDriver and read the sqlite3 database which the Chrome browser creates.

My problem is that the database is apparently empty, but in the Chrome browser window, I can see the cookies.

Here is my code and a screenshot of the browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os, shutil, sqlite3


browser_list_place = 0
browser_list = []
profiles_folder = "profiles"


def getcookies(url):
    if os.path.isdir(profiles_folder):
        shutil.rmtree(profiles_folder)

    co = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    co.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    co.add_argument("--user-data-dir=" + profiles_folder + "/" + str(browser_list_place))

    browser_list.append(webdriver.Chrome('D:\crawler\chromedriver.exe', options=co))
    browser_list[browser_list_place].set_page_load_timeout(30)

    browser_list[browser_list_place].get(url)

    #browser_list[browser_list_place].quit()

    for folder in range(0, browser_list_place + 1):
        con = sqlite3.connect(profiles_folder + "/" + str(folder) + "/Default/Cookies")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cookies")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print(row)


getcookies('https://developer.mozilla.org/de/')
```

[image]

Why is the database empty for my program?

Answer (score 1):

Use pickle to save and load cookies

```
import pickle as pk
pk.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))  # save cookies

cookies = pk.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))  # load cookies
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Comment: But gives me `driver.get_cookies()` all cookies also includes the third party cookies? Because Google Chrome shows 7 Cookies and `driver.get_cookies()` only 5 for the url above. And if i open the sqlite3 database with a sqlite browser it shows 6 cookies. Why?

Comment: Nope. I think selenium allows you to interact with cookies from current domain only.

Comment: Yes and this was the reason why i must read the sqlite3 database from Google Chrome because i think these includes all cookies...

Comment: Not sure if this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532870/encrypted-cookies-in-chrome

Comment: Maybe later. My current problem is that the database is sometimes empty and sometimes not also i open it with a sqlite browser and i don't know why. Deletes Google Chrome the cookies after a specific time or do i something wrong?

Comment: Or is there a more efficient way to get all cookies (first and third party) without selenium? The values is not so important for me but all other information like name, host, expires, ....

Comment: I cannot give you a very specific answer. Another package is `browsercookie` https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/browsercookie/ but when i tried it it didnt have permissions to the sqlite file so I quit trying.

Comment: Okay.. but have you an idea why the cookie database from chrome browser sometimes is empty?